# R Logic for Creating Variable of Ascending Order in Relation to Ascending INDEX Number (Long Format)

Tags: r, excel, automation, data-science, data-analysis

My goal is to create a variable in R with ascending lists based on a corresponding INDEX number. It may be simple logic with looping, but I haven't been able to identify the right vocabulary to research the right way since this logic/math has thus far not been part of my primary discipline. Because of this, I have been spinning my wheels with no luck when looking for reference sites.

I created the following in Excel to illustrate my goal:

[image: Desired Result for R Code]

So far, I have been grinding with a pretty manual code in Excel:

```
=IF(B2=1,0+10000000,"-")
=IF(B3=1,A2+1,"-")
=IF(n1=1,0+10000000,"-")
=IF(n1=1,m2+1,"-")
```

[image: Grind Logic in Excel]

I appreciate any insight into what vocabulary and logic can be utilized to accomplish my goal.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `%/%` to create this automatically

```
100:500 %/% 100
```

If the values are in 100s in the columns

```
df1$sort_order %/% 100
```

Change the value of 100 to 10000000 or so for the bigger numbers

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, you can change the multiplication to get as many 0's as needed.

```
id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
sort.order <- rep(0, length(id))
id.check <- id[1]
tick <- 0

for (i in 1:length(id)) {
  if (id[i] %in% id.check) {
    sort.order[i] <- (id[i] * 100) + tick
    tick <- tick + 1
  } else {
    id.check <- c(id.check, id[i])
    sort.order[i] <- id[i] * 100
    tick <- 1
  }
}

df <- data.frame(sort_order = sort.order, sentence_id = id)
```